# Creating variables from file input

Tags: c#, arrays, split

Help.  I'm a Perl guy who could accomplish this task in seconds using Perl, but I'm my C# solution seems overkill.  I have a file that I have opened and can read line by line.  I then need to convert some of the values I read into an array.

For example, here are two lines in the file that I'm processing:

```
"12/19/2016 11:13:30 AM",Error Recovery Histogram: 81920 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
"12/19/2016 11:13:30 AM",Failed Bit Histogram: 3187 78228 469 36 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I want to do is create an array for each of those lines and store the histogram values in the array.  This is done in two lines of Perl, but its getting a little messier with C#.  Here's what I have so far:

```
string sERH = "Error Recovery Histogram";
int erhPos = fLine.IndexOf(sERH);
string[] valsERH = new string[16];
string[] separators = { " " };
if (erhPos != -1)
{
    string subERH = fLine.Substring((erhPos + sERH.Length + 1));
    valsERH = subERH.Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.None);
    Console.WriteLine("          {0} - {1} --> {2}", erhPos, sERH.Length, subERH);

    for(int a=0; a<valsERH.Count(); a++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("          Values in array: {0}={1}", a,valsERH[a]);
    }
}
```

Here I can get the entire string of histogram values into a string 'subERH' and can then use the String.Split method.  This seems an incredibly clumsy way of doing it.  Is there a more efficient way?  Not to mention, this is currently storing the values as 'string', I'd still have to convert to 'int' if I want to start adding the values.  There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = new string[] {
        "\"12/19/2016 11:13:30 AM\",Error Recovery Histogram: 81920 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ",
        "\"12/19/2016 11:13:30 AM\",Failed Bit Histogram: 3187 78228 469 36 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
    };

    var timestampDelimiters = new string[] { "," };
    var msgDelimiters = new string[] { ":" };
    var numberDelimiters = new string[] { " " };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var msgTokens = line.Split(timestampDelimiters, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
        string timestamp = msgTokens[0];
        string message = msgTokens[1];

        var histTokens = message.Split(msgDelimiters, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
        string histogramTitle = histTokens[0];
        string histogramValues = histTokens[1];

        var entries = histogramValues.Split(numberDelimiters, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var numbersList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();

        //Iterate through entries and convert them
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            numbersList.Add(System.Convert.ToInt32(entry));
        }

        // Use it like a List, or convert it to an array with ToArray method
        System.Console.Write("{0}: {1} entries", histogramTitle, numbersList.ToArray().Length);
    }

    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, lots of good stuff here.  Thanks for the help, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sERH = "Error Recovery Histogram:";            //MAKE SURE YOU PUT THE : IN THERE!
int erhPos = fLine.IndexOf(sERH);
string[] valsERH = new string[16];                                             //WHY 16??

char spliter = ' ';                     //YOU ONLY NEED THE CHAR MARKER FOR YOUR SPLITTER
string[] subStrings = sERH.Split(spliter);                       //CREATE YOUR SUBSTRINGS
int[] iNumbers = new int[subStrings.Count()];                //CREATE YOUR ARRAY OF INT'S

for (int i = 0; i < subStrings.Count(); i ++)
{
    try
    {
        iNumbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(subStrings[i]);   //IF YOU CAN CONVERT IT TO AN INT
    }
    catch { }                                                   //OR LEAVE IT AS A STRING
}
```

For Display purposes, you can just use the `subString`'s.  There really isn't a need to convert them to an `int`, unless you need to pass those `int` values to something else.  If you do, then you can just work out the logic on that; and since you're getting formatted messages, you should just be able to break every one up starting at the `:`.  It may not be elegant, or 2 lines of code, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help... this is giving me some ideas for changes to the code.  Appreciate the help.  To answer the question, I used 16 because there will only ever be 16 values in the Error Recovery Histogram.